# Ubuntu 15.04 with Intel Integrated Graphics on X1 Carbon freezes frequently

Tags: 15.04, lenovo, chromium, freeze, intel

I have a Lenovo X1 Carbon 2015 with 8GB. I'm running Ubuntu 15.04 with 3.19.0-26 kernel on it.

Every so often (and  its quite frequent) my machine runs out of memory using Chromium, and then it would go to freeze/lock up the entire thing. I have no option then but to restart, and it has become a routine thing.

AFAI remember, this wasnt a problem on Ubuntu 14 (with an older kernel). I had to update to Ubuntu 15 with newer kernel because I'm powering 2 external monitors using the dock and only newer kernels supports extended desktop over 2 monitors.

Thanks in advance for replying,

Jeff

ninja edit - I somehow feels the swap isnt doing its business. There's no reason for the machine to lock up when you run out of memory, right? How do I check if swap is setup correctly?

Comment: I think you're running out of RAM because you're running three monitors on a computer with integrated graphics, not because you have 15.04. You can refer  [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-on-ubuntu-14-04) to see if there's anything useful about swap. I think a better troubleshooting step might be to unplug one monitor and see what happens. Intel Graphics aren't very powerful, so there may be something here.

Comment: It was indeed the swap. Shortly after I posted this question, I added a swap partition, and things have been pretty smooth. Thanks Zacharee1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was indeed the swap. Shortly after I posted this question, I added a swap partition, and things have been pretty smooth